# File not saving django

Tags: python, django

I'm generating a docx file with user input and trying to upload the file with `File` method but neither it gives an error nor it saves the file.

views.py

```
def schoolinput_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        worddocument = docx.Document()
        school_name_view = request.POST.get('school_name')
        documenttitle = worddocument.add_heading(school_name_view.title(), 0)
        path = join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'word_documents','quicktimetable.docx')
        documentfile = Timetables()
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            pass
        elif request.user.is_authenticated:
            documentfile.user = request.user
            document = File(path, worddocument)
            documentfile.save(document)
```

models.py

```
class Timetables(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=1, related_name='timetables_files', null=True, blank=True)
    timetable_files = models.FileField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to='word_documents')
```

The word file it's generating is not saving in the file storage. However in the admin panel it shows number of objects created in Timetables and the user for the files is also correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [FieldFile.save(name, content, save=True)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save).

In your case (provide your FieldFile **timetable_files** ):

```
documentfile.timetable_files.save(new_name,document)
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add the code for ```content``` I made with ```file_io = io.BytesIO()``` which I had to use instead of document and it worked.